# Django raw sql, getting the fields value from a row

Tags: python, sql, django

**Disclaimer:** the raw queries i've written bellow are dummies, my real queries are complicated and cannot be executed without raw query,

executing this sql:

```
   from django.db import connection, transaction
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT id, name, phone FROM table1 WHERE rule=1")
   result_list= cursor.fetchall()
```

next step require going over the `result_list` and execute a second query, in which i use the `name` parameter value in the where clause.

```
for row in result_list:
        sql_string = 'SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE name='+ row[1]
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_string)
        ids = cursor.fetchall()
```

**My Question:** How can I concatenate all the ids from the different iterations of the loop into a single `ids` array/list

the following is not what i'm looking for as I wish to have a single array/list of values and not an array of arrays/ list of lists

```
id_list = []
id_list.append(ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

The iteration over result_list will produce a query for each iteration. A better way to do this is to use the SQL `IN` operator and select all the `id`s for you second table in one query.

```
sql_string = 'SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE name IN (%s)'
cursor = connection.cursor()
# You should let cursor.execute handle string interpolation
cursor.execute(sql_string, [', '.join(x.name for x in result_list)]) 
id_list = [x.id for x in cursor.fetchall()]
```

The last line uses list comprehension to change the list of lists into a flat list containing all the `id`s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand the question, but perhaps you should be using `extend`:

```
id_list.extend(ids)
```